# On button click open a new window and draw a circle with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to open a new window on button click and draw a simple circle on it.

I can open a window but circle won't appear on it with this code. Any ideas on how to solve this.0

Here is my code:

```
function drawBarChart(newWindowRoot){
    var sampleSVG = d3.select(newWindowRoot)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);

    sampleSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});
}
function createNewPage(){

    var button = content.append("button")
            .attr("class", "button")
            .attr("id", "myButton")
            .text("Visualize");

    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {

        var newWindow = window.open('');
        newWindowRoot = d3.select(newWindow.document.body)
            .attr("width","1060px")
            .attr("margin","50px auto");

        drawBarChart(newWindowRoot);

    }

}
```

Comment: set up a JSFiddle and we can alter your code :)

Comment: I have added the demo link :)

Comment: your demo doesnt do anything :/

Comment: I think there is a problem with Fiddle. It works until I save it. You could maybe copy paste it to Fiddle. It should work if you replace `content` with `d3.select("body")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `drawBarChart(newWindowRoot)`, you're passing a d3 selection — the result of `d3.select(newWindow.document.body)` — into that function. That makes sense.

However, from within `drawBarChart`, you call `var sampleSVG = d3.select(newWindowRoot)`, essentially making a d3 selection of a d3 selection.  That doesn't work (unlike what you might expect from jQuery). You should skip that latter `d3.select` and that'll make your code begin to work. More specifically, that'll make the button appear in the new window, but not the circle.

To make the circle appear, you need to fix another issue: Your fiddle attempts to add the circle to the button, instead of to an SVG (this is different than your example above which isn't trying to create a button).

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/3/)

By the way, the reason the jsFiddle you linked to didn't work is because the link you embedded was using secure protocol (https) and the jsfiddle functionality that was trying to load d3 is insecure (http), which resulted in a failure to load d3 and in turn an error executing your code.