# On button click open a new window and draw multiple large circles with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This question has been answered before here: [On button click open a new window and draw a large circle with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211146/on-button-click-open-a-new-window-and-draw-a-large-circle-with-d3)

In the solution given by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark):
http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/38/

```
sampleSVG.append('svg')
.attr('width', 500)
.attr('height', 500) //<-- give the SVG some size
.append("circle")
.style("stroke", "gray")
.style("fill", "red")
.attr("r", 200)
.attr("cx", 250)
.attr("cy", 250)
...
```

I'm not able to understand how to append multiple circles to the same svg, say in a for loop.
How to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend the part that appends a single circle to append inside of the loop. Cast the result of the first svg append to a variable, then iterate and append to it:

```
var mySVG = sampleSVG.append('svg')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 500); //<-- give the SVG some size

for (var i=0; i < 250; i = i+10){
    mySVG.append("circle")
      .style("stroke", "gray")
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr("r", 200)
      .attr("cx", i)
      .attr("cy", i)
}
```